# springmvc get request query string param wrap to a pojo

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Controller

```
@GetMapping("/list")
public Result findUserInfo(@Valid UserFindParam param){
// TODO
}
```

Param

```
public class UserFindParam {

    public Integer age;

    public String keyword;

}
```

how to set the default value of the UserFindParam.age?

Example

```
@GetMapping("/list")
public Result findUserInfo(@RequestParam(name = "age", defaultValue = "12") int age,
                           @RequestParam(name = "keyword", requied = false) String keyword){
// TODO
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set the value in the POJO itself. For example:

```
public Integer age = 10;
```